# group by oracle

Tags: sql

I have a table as below:

```
id             value
-------------------------
1               1
5               1
7               1
8               4
```

I can't get to table as below:

```
id             value
-------------------------
1               1
8               4
```

The SQL is

```
select id,value from table_1 group by id_a
```

Comment: never mind -looks like you got the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have here is a simple `MIN()` aggregate.

```
SELECT MIN(id), value AS id FROM table_1 GROUP BY value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select min(id), id_a from table_1 group by id_a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.value,MIN(id) AS MIN_ID 
FROM TABLE T
GROUP BY T.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a group by expression, you must have one or more aggregating functions: count, min, max, sum, avg etc.  These functions operate on a group of rows at a time.  Now when you use an aggregate function with a none aggregated column(s) you need to use the group by clause.

The below will give you the correct answer:

```
select min(id) id, value from table_1 group by value
```